# Segmentation fault in std function std::_Rb_tree_rebalance_for_erase ()

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, std

(Note to any future readers: The error, unsurprisingly, is in my code and not std::_Rb_tree_rebalance_for_erase () )

I'm somewhat new to programming and am unsure how to deal with a segmentation fault that appears to be coming from a std function. I hope I'm doing something stupid (i.e., misusing a container), because I have no idea how to fix it.

The precise error is

> Program received signal EXC_BAD_ACCESS, Could not access memory.
>   Reason: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at address: 0x000000000000000c
>   0x00007fff8062b144 in std::_Rb_tree_rebalance_for_erase ()
>   (gdb) backtrace
>    #0  0x00007fff8062b144 in std::_Rb_tree_rebalance_for_erase ()
>    #1  0x000000010000e593 in Simulation::runEpidSim (this=0x7fff5fbfcb20) at stl_tree.h:1263
>    #2  0x0000000100016078 in main () at main.cpp:43

The function that exits successfully just before the segmentation fault updates the contents of two containers. One is a `boost::unordered_multimap` called `carriage`; it contains one or more `struct Infection` objects. The other container is of type `std::multiset< Event, std::less< Event > > EventPQ` called `ce`.

```
void Host::recover( int s, double recoverTime, EventPQ & ce ) {

  // Clearing all serotypes in carriage
  // and their associated recovery events in ce
  // and then updating susceptibility to each serotype
  double oldRecTime;
  int z;
  for ( InfectionMap::iterator itr = carriage.begin(); itr != carriage.end(); itr++ ) {
    z = itr->first;
    oldRecTime = (itr->second).recT;
    EventPQ::iterator epqItr = ce.find( Event(oldRecTime) );
    assert( epqItr != ce.end() );
    ce.erase( epqItr );
    immune[ z ]++; 
  }
  carriage.clear();
  calcSusc(); // a function that edits an array 
  cout << "Done with sync_recovery event." << endl;
}
```

The last `cout <<`  line appears immediately before the seg fault.

My idea so far is that the rebalancing is being attempted on `ce` immediately after this function, but I am unsure why the rebalancing would be failing.

---

**Update**

I've confirmed the seg fault goes away (though the program then immediately crashes for other reasons) when I remove `ce.erase( epqItr );`. I am able to remove events  successfully in another place in the code; the code I use there to erase items in `ce` is *identical* to what's here.

Backtracing *without* optimization (thanks, bdk) reveals much more information:

> Program received signal EXC_BAD_ACCESS, Could not access memory.
>   Reason: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at address: 0x000000000000000c
>   0x00007fff8062b144 in std::_Rb_tree_rebalance_for_erase ()
>   (gdb) backtrace
>    #0  0x00007fff8062b144 in std::_Rb_tree_rebalance_for_erase ()
>    #1  0x00000001000053d2 in std::_Rb_tree, std::less, > std::allocator >::erase (this=0x7fff5fbfdfe8, __position={_M_node = 0x10107cb50}) at > stl_tree.h:1263
>    #2  0x0000000100005417 in std::multiset, std::allocator >::erase (this=0x7fff5fbfdfe8, __position={_M_node = 0x10107cb50}) at stl_multiset.h:346
>    #3  0x000000010000ba71 in Simulation::runEpidSim (this=0x7fff5fbfcb40) at Simulation.cpp:426
>    #4  0x000000010001fb31 in main () at main.cpp:43

Unless Xcode is reading line numbers wrong, the only stl_tree.h in my hard drive is blank on line 1263.

A few people asked to see the function that calls recover. It's a bit complicated:

```
struct updateRecovery{
updateRecovery( int s, double t, EventPQ & ce ) : s_(s), t_(t), ce_(ce) {}
  void operator() (boost::shared_ptr<Host> ptr ) {
   ptr->recover( s_, t_, ce_ );
  }
private:
  int s_;
  double t_;
  EventPQ & ce_;
};

// allHosts is a boost::multiindex container of boost::shared_ptr< Host > 
// currentEvents is the EventPQ container
// it is an iterator to a specific member of allHosts
allHosts.modify( it, updateRecovery( s, t, currentEvents ) );
cout << "done with recovery" << endl;
```

The last `cout` prints. The code worked before without this particular version of the recovery function.

Noah Roberts correctly pointed out that the problem is at Simulation.cpp, line 426. Jump below for embarrassing solution.

Comment: The only stl_tree.h that shows up in my hard drive (also the only file containing '_Rb_tree_rebalance_for_erase' on my HD) is *blank* on line 1263 (?!). I'm using gcc 4.2.1 (Apple build 5646) on i686-apple-darwin10. The rebalance_for_erase function is defined on lines 299-429.

Comment: If you put a cout in the calling code right after the call to Host::recover, does that print out? Also, try compiling with all optimizations and inlining turned off and you may get a more useful stack trace

Comment: are you sure assert is enabled?  Perhaps try throwing exception instead. also check if immune array is not being overwritten past boundaries

Comment: It would be good if you could post the function that calls recover(). I'd like to see what happens to `ce` after recover() finishes.

Comment: This could result from any other portion of your code that happens to write outside its memory. Maybe you could try a memory checker like Memcheck: http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/mc-manual.html

Comment: @Thomas. Thanks, hadn't heard of it. Will start working with it.

Comment: "Simulation::runEpidSim (this=0x7fff5fbfcb40) at Simulation.cpp:426" sounds like the code you pasted above is not the problem code.  Your previously pasted error was similar but said it was somewhere else: "#1 0x000000010000e593 in Simulation::runEpidSim (this=0x7fff5fbfcb20) at stl_tree.h:1263"  What does Simulation::runEpidSim look like and what's at Simulation.cpp:426?

Comment: Awesome peeps here. Just when I want to ask @Sarah a question someone beets me to it. ^^  But yeah, I feel the problem is somewhere along the line you pass an invalid iterator. It may be in `Simulation.cpp:426` or somewhre higher in the stacktrace. But `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` is usually a thick hint for dereferencing (or asking a standard function to dereference) an invalid iterator.

Comment: @Noah: You're right. At that line, I attempt to delete an event that has just been deleted in the recover() function. Massive fail. Thank you. I will revise my question so this is useful to others in posterity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possibly you're holding onto an iterator into `ce` across the call to recover. If recover happens to remove that item the iterator will be invalidated and any future use (say an attempt to erase it) could result in a seg fault.

It would help if we could see more context of how `ce` is used before and after the call to recover.

Comment: You're right! (I need to look into how and when tree rebalancing happens.)

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that on line 426 of Simulation.cpp, I tried to delete an event in the `EventPQ currentEvents` (a.k.a. `ce`) container that my `recover()` function had just deleted. The iterator had obviously been invalidated. Dumb.

Lessons:

- **Debug on code that has not been optimized**
- Pay close attention to what the non-std related frames imply

And for the future: Trace memory in valgrind

I'm still stumped why the debugger referred me to an apparently blank line in stl_tree.h.

I've massive appreciation here for the people who have helped me work through this. I'm going to revise my question so it's more concise for any future readers.

Comment: That's a general rule to follow when you run into a crash.  Look at the callstack from the top down until you hit your own code and start looking there.  Generally you'll find that the bug is caused somewhere in that stacktrace within your own code, not the library.  When that's not the case you'll usually find you hit UB a half hour ago and are just now running into whatever that caused.  I've actually never run into a library bug.  Run into a LOT of compiler bugs but I can't think of any library bug.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the call to `assert` is not compiled with your configuration. Assertions in production code are usually a Bad Idea[TM].

You could also be exceeding `immune`'s boundaries.

Try:

```
    if (epqItr != ce.end()) 
    {
        ce.erase(epqItr);
        if (z is within immune's bounds)
        {
            ++immune[z]; 
        }
    }
```