# C++ map.erase() causes unwanted balancing

Tags: c++, multithreading, dictionary, segmentation-fault

I have a `map<uint, Order*> orders` where Order is a defined class with applicable fields such as id, time, price and volume. I also have a thread which listens for incoming order additions and deletions for the map defined below.

```
void System::OrderDeleted_Thread(unsigned int order_id)
{
    if(orders.find(order_id) != orders.end())
    {
            Order* order = orders[order_id];
            orders.erase(order_id);
            delete order;
    }
}
```

My problem is very similar to this one:

[Segmentation fault in std function std::_Rb_tree_rebalance_for_erase ()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2869183/1143465)

My question is, how can I iterate through my orders map without the program giving me an error when it comes time to re balance the tree? Just like the solution in the link says, I have taken out the .erase(uint) method and gotten it to work. Unfortunately, I cannot keep a map of several tens of thousands keys around.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you add some more detail about the synchronizing of your threads - in particular do you allow one thread to read while another deletes?Also, what are your constraints, a map of <uint, pointer> is easily within the memory capabilities of most machines?

Comment: @TimGee I do allow threads to add as well as delete. Throughout the day there could by upwards of 100k-200k entries, wouldn't it take too long to search for a specific order by key?

Comment: I think your problem is thread synchronization and is being answered elsewhere. On the performance cost of a 100k-200k map - note that maps have logarithmic lookup performance. In English - they are extremely fast even on maps this size.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I also have a thread which listens for incoming order additions and deletions for the map defined below.

You need to synchronize access to the map. STL containers are not thread-safe with multiple writers (and erasing elements is writing to the container) without some sort of external synchronization.

Comment: I added a mutex around the orders.erase(order_id) line, but it is still having the same issues... or is this not what you are referring to?

Comment: @Joshua, you need to use that mutex around every use of the map if you are going to modify it from a different thread.

Comment: You have to synchronize *all* operations including iteration and finds, not just the erase.

Comment: the map can change its state everytime you use it, especially with `operator[]` so I think you should mutex that, too.

Comment: You need to synchronize *all* accesses to the map, not just the erase.

Comment: Hmm ok, ideally I would like a synchronized, unordered map. Do those exist in C++ (Hashtable from Java). I will check google, but I was wondering if someone knew of a good one already.

Comment: @Joshua That wouldn't help you. Even a synchronized, unordered map can't magically remain synchronized against multiple calls into the map. You call `find`, `end`, `operator[]`, and `erase` and you need the map to stay unmodified all the way from the `find` to the `erase` or you fail.

Comment: Depending on your compiler, you could resort to `<concurrent_vector>` in Visual Studio 2010+, with `pair<Key,Value>` as the `value_type` and keeping it ordered yourself, etc etc, effectively emulating a `concurrent_map` (which they sadly don't have).

Answer (score 1):

Queue up your additions and deletions in a seperate data structure, and then process them at a safe time, that is when you are guaranteed to not be iterating through the map.  That safe time can be after you have acquired a mutex which protects the map, or some other way, depending on your program.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from synchronisation issues, that's a costly way to write the loop. Instead, try this:

```
std::map<uint, Order*>::iterator it;
Order * p = NULL;

{ // enter critical section
    if ((it = orders.find(id)) != orders.end())
    {
        p = it->second;
        orders.erase(it);
    }
} // leave critical section

delete p;
```

Comment: True, but really doesn't answer the OP's question.

Comment: @BillyONeal: True... I don't think we can solve the OP's issue without seeing more code. My bet is on a synchronization issue, and my answer will make the synchronized solution less costly, if that's worth anything :-S (In fact I just added a little improvement.)

Comment: @KerrekSB Thanks, Can you explain why it is cheaper to have that iterator, rather than just seeing if it exists, then getting it using the [] operator?

Comment: @Joshua: This way you don't have to search the map twice.